# Change Table Mapping at runtime

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework (.net)
We have various departments and One table with different table names has same schema across all departments. like if Department Name is ABC and DEF the table name is ABC_TimeSeries and DEF_Timeseries respectively.
I have created a one class. Now I would like to change the tables name as user selects the department using drop-down selection box.

Answer (score 0):

In your case that you have suffixes, I think Brandon Haynes solution -[Entity Framework Runtime Model Adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/)- can help.

But I'm going to use interfaces and dependency injection for my similar problem.